# What is the difference between background and background-color

Tags: css, background, background-color

What's the difference between specifying a background color using `background` and `background-color`?

**Snippet #1**

```
body { background-color: blue; }
```

**Snippet #2**

```
body { background: blue; }
```

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Premising that those are two distinct properties, in your specific example there's no difference in the result, since [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) actually is a shorthand for

> ```
> background-color  
> background-image  
> background-position  
> background-repeat  
> background-attachment  
> background-clip  
> background-origin  
> background-size
> ```

Thus, besides the [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color), using the `background` shorthand you could also add one or more values without repeating any other  `background-*` property more than once.

Which one to choose is essentially up to you, but it could also depend on specific conditions of your style declarations (e.g if you need to override just the `background-color` when inheriting other related `background-*` properties from a parent element, or if you need to remove all the values except the `background-color`).

Comment: So `background` is just a shortcut for any of the 5 attributes? Hence not practical in real life if there are background position, color, and image?

Comment: It's very practical, because you can specify all those attributes *in one line*. Refer to the [Official Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background)

Comment: there is A difference. i have a div with transparent gaps between its child elements when using background-color. but it is completely solid when i just use background. there is a verifiable difference in either their properties or behavior.

Comment: Fwiw, from @ChristianVarga's link: *The 'background' property is a shorthand property for setting the individual background properties (i.e., 'background-color', 'background-image', 'background-repeat', 'background-attachment' and 'background-position') at the same place in the style sheet. Given a valid declaration, the 'background' property first sets all the individual background properties to their initial values, then assigns explicit values given in the declaration.* Example given: `P { background: url("chess.png") gray 50% repeat fixed }`

Comment: More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: How about --background?

Answer (score 176):

`background` will supercede all previous `background-color`, `background-image`, etc. specifications. It's basically a shorthand, but a **reset** as well.

I will sometimes use it to overwrite previous `background` specifications in template customizations, where I would want the following:

`background: white url(images/image1.jpg) top left repeat;`

to be the following:

`background: black;`

So, all parameters (`background-image`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`) will reset to their default values.

Comment: This is a more complete answer, the reset part is very important difference.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background -> As with all css shorthand properties, any omitted sub-values will be set to their initial value > background-image: none
background-position: 0% 0%
background-size: auto auto
background-repeat: repeat
background-origin: padding-box
background-clip: border-box
background-attachment: scroll
background-color: transparent

Answer (score 101):

About **CSS performance** :

**`background`** vs **`background-color`** :

> Comparison of 18 color swatches rendered 100 times on a page as small
>   rectangles, once with **background** and once with **background-color**.

[image: Background vs background-color]

> While these numbers are from a single page reload, with subsequent
>   refreshes the render times changed, but the percent difference was
>   basically the same every time.
>
> **That's a savings of almost 42.6ms, almost twice as fast**, when using
>   background instead of background-color in Safari 7.0.1. Chrome 33
>   appears to be about the same.
>
> This honestly blew me away because for the longest time for two reasons:
>
> - I usually always argue for explicitness in CSS properties, especially with backgrounds because it can adversely affect specificity down the road.
> - I thought that when a browser sees `background: #000;`, they really see `background: #000 none no-repeat top center;`. I don't have a link to a resource here, but I recall reading this somewhere.

**Ref :** https://github.com/mdo/css-perf#background-vs-background-color

Comment: Can you also say that all CSS shorthands are more preferreble due to the better performance?

Comment: @LeventDivilioglu As tester said : `These kind of tests are cheats and always going to be somewhat inaccurate from the real world` https://github.com/mdo/css-perf#updated-conclusions-from-averages

Answer (score 28):

With `background` you can set all `background` properties like:

- `background-color`
- `background-image`
- `background-repeat`
- `background-position`
  ***etc.***

---

With `background-color` you can just specify the color of the background

```
background: url(example.jpg) no-repeat center center #fff;
```

*VS.*

```
background-image: url(example.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #fff;
```

---

### [More info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

***(See Caption: Background - Shorthand property)***

Answer (score 8):

One of the difference:

If you use a image as background in this way:

```
background: url('Image Path') no-repeat;
```

then you cannot override it with "background-color" property.

But if you are using background to apply a color, it is same as background-color and can be overriden.

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/Z57Za/11/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Z57Za/12/

Answer (score 4):

I've found that you cannot set a gradient with background-color.

**This works:**

```
background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
```

**This doesn't:**

```
background-color:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the `background` shorthand property sets several background-related properties. It sets them all, even if you only specify e.g. a color value, since then the other properties are set to their initial values, e.g. `background-image` to `none`.

This does not mean that it would always override any other settings for those properties. This depends on the cascade according to the usual, generally misunderstood rules.

In practice, the shorthand tends to be somewhat safer. It is a precaution (not complete, but useful) against accidentally getting some unexpected background properties, such as a background image, from another style sheet. Besides, it’s shorter. But you need to remember that it really means “set all background properties”.

Answer (score 2):

*There is no difference.* Both will work in the same way.

> > CSS background properties are used to define the background effects of
> >     an element.
> >
> > CSS properties used for background effects:
>
> - background-color
> - background-image
> - background-repeat
> - background-attachment
> - background-position

Background property includes all of this properties and you can just write them in one line.

Answer (score 2):

> Comparison of 18 color swatches rendered 100 times on a page as small
>   rectangles, once with background and once with background-color.

I recreated the **CSS performance** experiment and the results are  significantly different nowadays.

```
background
```

**Chrome 54**: 443 (µs/div)

**Firefox 49**: 162 (µs/div)

**Edge 10**: 56 (µs/div)

```
background-color
```

**Chrome 54**: 449 (µs/div)

**Firefox 49**: 171 (µs/div)

**Edge 10**: 58 (µs/div)

As you see - there's almost no difference.

Answer (score 2):

`background` is the shortcut for `background-color` and few other background related stuffs as below:

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

Read the statement below from W3C:

> #### Background - Shorthand property
>
> To shorten the code, it is
>   also possible to specify all the background properties in one single
>   property. This is called a shorthand property.
>
> The shorthand property for background is background:

```
body {
  background: white url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:

> ```
> background-color
> background-image
> background-repeat
> background-attachment
> background-position
> ```
>
> It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long
>   as the other ones are in this order.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer. Shorthand (background) is for reset and DRY (combine with longhand).

Answer (score 1):

`background` is shorthand property for the following:

```
 - background-color
 - background-image
 - background-repeat
 - background-attachment
 - background-position
```

You can detailed info on every property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

**Properties order**

In most of browser implementation (i think maybe older browser could present issues) the order of the properties does not matter, except for:

- `background-origin` and `background-clip`: when both of this properties are present, the first one refer to `-origin` and the second to `-clip`.

  Example:

  ```
  background: content-box green padding-box;
  ```

  Is equivalent to:

  ```
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-color: green;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  ```
- `background-size` must always follow `background-position` and the properties must be separated by `/`
- if `background-position` is composed by two numbers, the first one is the horizontal value and the second the vertical value.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed when generating emails for Outlook...

```
/*works*/
background: gray;

/*does not work*/
background-color: gray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some pretty neat stuff once you understand that you can play with inheritance with this. However first let's understand something from this [doc on background:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

> With CSS3, you can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are
>   layered atop one another with the first background you provide on top
>   and the last background listed in the back. Only the last background
>   can include a background color.

So when one do:

```
background: red;
```

He is setting the background-color to red because red is the last value listed.

When one do:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 50%, yellow 2%) red;
```

Red is the background color once again **BUT** you will see a gradient.

```css
    .box{
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 50%, yellow 2%) red;
    }

    .box::before{
       content: "";
       display: block;
       margin-left: 50%;
       height: 50%;
       border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
       transform: translateX(70px) translateY(-26px) rotate(325deg);
       background: inherit;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
      
     </div>
```

Now the same thing with background-color:

```css
    .box{
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 50%, yellow 2%) red;
    }

    .box::before{
       content: "";
       display: block;
       margin-left: 50%;
       height: 50%;
       border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
       transform: translateX(70px) translateY(-26px) rotate(325deg);
       background-color: inherit;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
      
     </div>
```

The reason this happens is because when we are doing this :

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 50%, yellow 2%) #red;
```

The last number sets the background-color.

Then in the before we are inheriting from background (then we get the gradient) or background color, then we get red.

Answer (score -2):

One thing I've noticed that I don't see in the documentation is using 
`background: url("image.png")`

short hand like above if the image is not found it sends a 302 code instead of being ignored like it is if you use

```
background-image: url("image.png")
```

Answer (score -2):

There's a bug regarding with background and background-color

the difference of this,
when using background, sometimes when your creating a webpage
in CSS
background: #fff // can over ride a block of Mask image("top item, text or image"))
so its better to always use background-color
for safe use, in your design if its individual

Comment: Sorry that doesnt make sense. Can you edit your answer to elaborate more on that?