# Setting the color of text to a parent Div's background color

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/EBPg9/2/

I'm working on a little project where I have multiple multicolored items, and tags within them.  Instead of specifying my color for both text and background, I'd like to just get the background color of my parent div and assign it to the color of my text.

My current jQuery looks like this:

```
$(".infobox").each(function() {
     var tagcolor =    $(this).closest('.info').css('background');
     $(this).css('color',tagcolor);
     alert(tagcolor);
});
```

My HTML is

```
<div class="info" style="background: #408FCE;">
    <div class="infobox">
        tags
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from my jQuery, I created an alert that will show me the value of the variable "tagcolor", and weirdly it seems to be getting all other unwanted CSS values, even though I specified "Background".  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, how can I fix this?

EDIT: Did some reseach here;

[What is the difference between background and background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205464/whats-the-difference-between-specifying-background-vs-background-color-in)

Apparantly "background" returns a bunch of different stuff.

Comment: Wow! Look at all those answers! It's like feeding pigeons in the park.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PakN6/)</kbd>

use `background-color` instead of `background`

```
var tagcolor = $(this).closest('.info').css('background-color');
```

see all properties of [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

`.css('background-color')` return all `background` properties that are set by ur `css` and `browser`

Comment: why down-voted ?? did i miss something ?? down-voter pls comment .

Comment: No idea why someone would downvote. I upvoted since you're the only person to actually include why this works. I'll select as best answer when it opens up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "`background`" property to apply a bunch of values regarding the background such as:

```
background: #123456 url('http://www.path.to.your.image.com') left top no-repeat;
```

It's much shorter than:

```
background-color:#123456;
background-image:'http://www.path.to.your.image.com';
background-position:left top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

When you retrieve the '`background`' property, you get all of the values (default if not specified). Instead just query for the css "`background-color`" property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `background-color`  instead of `background`

```
$(".infobox").each(function() {
     var tagcolor =    $(this).closest('.info').css('background-color');
     $(this).css('color',tagcolor);
     alert(tagcolor);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/EBPg9/5/)</kbd>

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background,
>   border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.
>   (Taken from :  http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Use background-color instead and it will work.

```
$(".infobox").each(function() {
     var tagcolor =    $(this).closest('.info').css('background-color');
     $(this).css('color',tagcolor);
     alert(tagcolor);
});

<div class="info" style="background-color: #408FCE;">
    <div class="infobox">
        tags
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
$(".infobox").each(function() {
     var tagcolor =    $(this).closest('.info').css('backgroundColor');
     $(this).css('color',tagcolor);
     alert(tagcolor);
});
```

Comment: background is a kinda compound css style, as backgroundColor is the specific attribute for the color

Comment: @AlexanderLozada `background` is a shorthand method that sets different properties, one of which is `background-color`. Therefore you can't set the value of `color` to the value of `background`.

Answer (score 0):

`background` contains a lot more than just the color!

Try specifying `background-color`:

```
$(".infobox").each(function() {
     var tagcolor =    $(this).closest('.info').css('background-color');
     $(this).css('color',tagcolor);
     alert(tagcolor);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EBPg9/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.infobox').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).css({
            color : $(this).parent().css('background-color')
        })
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EBPg9/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background-color instead of background