# Input tag of type button is not changing color in an ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

In our ASP.NET MVC 4 app, we are using following HTML tag of type button in a partial view but the button is still showing the default background color instead of the one we define in the style attribute as shown below:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Details..." id="btnDetails" style="white-space: normal; width:250px;background-color:green;" />
```

We have checked that the class "myClass" is not doing anything related to CSS. It seems something somewhere in the app is keeping it from applying the color attribute.

**Edit**

1. I've removed he class attribute from the input tag above since it is not doing anything related to CSS. Still the background color does not change. What is interesting is that if I change the other values in style above such as width etc., the button's style changes accordingly
2. Moreover, if I move the style attribute to a class in a stylesheet then also background-color does not work all other values in the class work.
3. The app is using JQuery-ui and has a jquery.ui.button.css file inside the Content\themes\base folder.
4. The app has a script file StartScript.js that has the following line of code at the very top:
   `$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#tabs").tabs();
   $("input[type=submit], input[type=button]").button();
   ...`
5. The following files have some button related scripts: jquery-1.7.1.js, jquery-1.7.1.min.js
6. I've used the !important keyword with the background-color as suggested [here](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/). But still no change in background-color

**Resolved**

I resolved the issue. Please see my comments at the end.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this it should work, anyway you can link to where the problem occurs?

Comment: Could you include the css used on myClass?

Comment: Post a link to the problem and on a side note, please stop using inline css.

Comment: This is an intrAnet web app. I've added an **Edit** section at the end of my post above for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use any debugger tool of any browser, it might be possible you have applied CSS on input Tag, but somehow link to css file is missing. even try to change attributes from debugger tool by you surely got solution to this.

Comment: I changed the attribute name from background-color to background and it started working. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205464/whats-the-difference-between-specifying-background-vs-background-color-in/10205537#10205537 for more details. Specially a response from Ankit on the above post was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that, instead of using css inline, you use a different class to each status. For example:

```
.status-ok {
    background-color: green;
}
.status-error {
    background-color: red;
}
```

You can have something like `class="myClass status-ok"`in your html.

Also, make sure no other css is overwriting your `background-color` property. You can do so by using any html inspector.