# Parse Error background:#7a7a7a

Tags: css, validation

This is my CSS Code. W3C CSS validator saying the above error.

Please provide suggestions

```
span.selected {
    width:70px;
    text-indent:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    background:#7a7a7a;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: According to http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input - "Congratulations! No Error Found"

Comment: There is no error in your background definition. What's the exact validator error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a manual check using http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator - which gave back

> Congratulations! No Error Found.

Try using `background-color` instead.

Please refer to this SO question: [What is the difference between background and background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205464/whats-the-difference-between-specifying-background-vs-background-color-in)

#### Docs

- [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to just set the color, use Background-color instead;

```
background-color: #7a7a7a;
```