# What is the main difference in background property in CSS3?

Tags: css

I want to know that what is the main difference between these properties

```
body {
background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

and

```
body {
background: url("paper.gif");
}
```

both above properties results in a same way, showing a background image, and we can also put the color like that too

`body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    }`

and

```
body {
background: #cccccc;
}
```

both above properties results in a light grey background color, so what's the main difference between these properties?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205464/what-is-the-difference-between-background-and-background-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background property is a shortcut, which allows you to specify multiple parameters in one statement. For example, you could use:

```
background: #00ff00 url("background.png") no-repeat fixed center;
```

When you use the background-color property, you are specifically setting only the color. Therefore, in your examples, there is effectively no difference - the end result will be the same whichever method you use.