# CSS color vs. background-color vs. background?

Tags: html, css

In HTML when do I use color, and what is the difference between background-color and also the background tag?

What are the differences?

Comment: Welcome Ivo. Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Search and Research first as @Barthy suggests

Comment: @Barthy That is exactly why it has been downvoted. It shows lack of research.

Comment: just because something is documented somewhere else doesn't mean you can't ask about it on SO

Comment: @DaveCousineau It is been downvoted as Dalija Prasnikar said because it shows a lack of rescouce and in the (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it says you should show some research.

Comment: This is the top result for the question and I'm using duckduckgo. So yes, a few seconds of internet search brings someone here and that isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Se ehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205464/what-is-the-difference-between-background-and-background-color for the difference between bg and bg-color

Answer (score 260, accepted):

`color` is referring to the text color in that element.

`background-color` refers to the background color

`background` is shorthand to combine many background tags into one line.

```
background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
```

Combines color, image and background image properties in the one line instead of typing our each style individually.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Comment: A teacher is there to tell us how it's done and solve doubts from whoever is reading the books: give simple answers to simple questions. But not everybody can pay for a good teacher. To me the important is to learn, and it's not everyday we have time and energy to dig into hidden answers. If your division was right, then this site would not have much merit.

Answer (score 13):

It is true that `background` gives more options versus `background-color`.  But if you only need to set background color, they are exactly the same, and each will override the other as seen in the snippet.

```
background: yellow;
```

```
background-color: yellow;
```

```css
.bc {
  background: yellow;
  background-color: green;
}

.bc2 {
  background-color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='bc'>
  bc { background:yellow; background-color:green; }
</div>

<div class='bc2'>
  bc { background-color:green; background:yellow; }
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Quick answer

- Color = Text Color
- Background-color = the color of the background
- Background = gives you the posibillity to set color, image , etc...

great tutorials on this are found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Answer (score 10):

I will give you a example using this html element:

`<span class="value"> This is my text </span>`

`.value { color: red, background-color: black}`

The CSS color is used to change the text color of a html element. In this example "This is my text" would be red. The CSS background-color is used to change the background color so in this case you would get a black box with red text inside it. Finally the background is used to set all the background properties in one declaration. For example:

`background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat fixed center;`

This changes the background color, adds the image "smiley.gif" to the background and it centers the image, it doesnt repeat the image if it has the space.

Answer (score 9):

One big thing about this both css properties is, that a background-color does not overwrite an image or a gradient that has been set with this:

```css
background:url('https://example.com/image.jpg');
```

or

```css
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 20%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);
```

If you are trying to change the background from an image to a color you have to use the background property.

Comment: Thank you very much for the overwrite hint. Ran into a case where my background was not working because of a gradient call elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

**color:** is used to add color to the Text within the Tag.

```css
color: blue;
```

**background-color:** is used to add color in background of the content inside the tag.

```css
background-color : red;
```

**background:** is used for adding different type of background property name to the content within the Tag.

```css
background : red url('image.png') fixed repeat cover;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Let me give you some definitions and examples.

1. The `color` property specifies the color of text.

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
```

2. The `background-color` property sets the background color of an element.

```css
div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

3. The `background` property is a shorthand property that allows you to set multiple background-related properties in one declaration. These properties include `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-position`, and others.

Instead of doing:
[source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_shorthand.asp)

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("img_tree.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
}
```

You can do:

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```