# HTML DOM change style of Parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function cross() {
  var dik = document.getElementsByName('r1c1')[0].parentNode;
  dik.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="FALSE"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="FALSE"></td>
  </tr>

  <input type="button" name="sbmt" value="CHECK" onclick="cross();">

</table>
```

When i click the button , I want to change color of **td** block to red that contains 
input element `<input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="TRUE">`

Comment: Your code works except `color` applies to text only. Your `td`s have no text node. https://jsfiddle.net/sa355spw/

Comment: Just change dik.style.background = "red";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use property `backgroundColor` to change the color of `td`. `color` is used to change the color of the `text`

[Read Here color vs backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033070/css-color-vs-background-color-vs-background)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function cross(){
    var dik = document.getElementsByName('r1c1')[0].parentNode;
    dik.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="FALSE"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="FALSE"></td>
</tr>

<input type="button" name="sbmt" value="CHECK" onclick="cross();">

</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `backgroundColor` rather than color:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function cross() {
    var dik = document.getElementsByName('r1c1')[0].parentNode;
    dik.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="FALSE"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="FALSE"></td>
  </tr>

  <input type="button" name="sbmt" value="CHECK" onclick="cross();">

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

try with `backgroundColor` instead of `color`

`color is change the text of color not background-color`

```
dik.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```js
function cross() {
  var dik = document.getElementsByName('r1c1')[0].parentNode;
  dik.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c1" value="FALSE"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="TRUE"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="r1c2" value="FALSE"></td>
  </tr>

  <input type="button" name="sbmt" value="CHECK" onclick="cross();">

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background color of the element to make it go red.

```
dik.style.background = "red";
```