# css difference between background: and background-image:

Tags: css, background, background-image, between, difference

quick simple question
In the following example of an external CSS page;

```
body {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
}
header {
  background: url(background.jpg);
}
```

I understand they are effecting different element selectors, my question is what is the difference between using background vs background-image? Does one have access to specific attributes to the other? Please and thank you.

Comment: Related post - [What is the difference between background and background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10205464/465053)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In a background property you can add `background-color`, `repeat`, `no-repeat` and other image attributes, but in the `background-image` property you are only allowed to add image.

```
background-image: url("img_tree.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

and in background property you can do in one line all these

```
background: #ccc url(paper.gif) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

By using background, you need to specify other argument to set the background of the page. If you just used background-image, it will only need a single argument.

```
background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;
```

Comment: Not true. You can, for example, just set a single property like this: `background: url(someURL);`.