# Background image is not showing in the div

Tags: html, css

```css
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 350px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;

  
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" style="background: url('~/images/hdpic.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:cover">
</div>
```

My image url is correct but i do't now why it is not working. if any one know please help me. Thanks.

Comment: try a full path for background url

Comment: Yeah the tilde (`~`) won't work client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your background image path, I've replaced the image path by another and it works.

Maybe replace the '`~`' by a relative path like '`../`'

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300') no-repeat; background-size:cover">
</div>
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9bd4zr2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, changed `background` to `background-image`,

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('~/images/hdpic.jpg') no-repeat; 
background-size:cover">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608030/4493442). Try using `background-image`. See below:

```css
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 350px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;

  
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('~/images/hdpic.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:cover">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('~/images/hdpic.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:cover">
</div>
```

Use `background-image` instead of `background`.

Answer (score 0):

The background css logic seems to be fine. Then you should check that the div is being shown has the proper size with the browser's inspector (has it got width...?)