# The code on the 2 pages doesn't do the same role. Can someone please help and explain?

Tags: css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5),
    rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)
    ), url("img/background.jpg");
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QrE2.jpg)]

The gradient linear repeats in page 2 while it doesn't in the page 1 despite the code being the same.

Comment: Are you using CSS3?

Comment: What do you mean by page 1 and page 2? There is only one image.

Comment: Check that body has a height set properly. At the moment it won’t extend beyond content. Force it to have min-height 100vh and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height to `100vh` and set the `width: 100%;`

And if you are applying it on 2 pages then add the stylesheet correctly in `head` section of the page then it will work for sure.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    /* height: 100%; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)), url("https://picsum.photos/1500/1500?random=1");
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>    
</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain your recommendation about using background. I cannot see anything wrong with the background-image setting given in the question.

Comment: I can remember I explained it before to you in another question and the explanation is also here in this answer but still will provide you a reference [when to use background and when to use background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607999/css-difference-between-background-and-background-image) I understand, in many cases like this it will still work but that doesn't mean it is correct.

Comment: This really doesn’t explain why background-image as given is incorrect. It is perfectly correct.

Comment: OK, I see in this case `background-image` property does take the `linear-gradient` parameter with the image URL successfully and works. But my point was in most cases, it only takes an image URL or multiple image URLs but not multiple different arguments.

Comment: You are confusing multiple instances of the same type of value, image in this case, separated by commas, with multiple instances of different types, e.g. size, image, position, which  all come within one value.