# CSS button not changing colour during hover (css and html)

Tags: html, css

For some reason my code is not allowing me to change the background colour of my button when I hover over it.

```css
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0.3em 1.2em;
    margin:0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
    border:0.16em solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-radius:2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    text-align:center;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    background-color:#f14e4e
}

.button.new-quote:hover {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="new-quote button" value= 'test'/>
```

Thank you for any help. I've tried making the selector a button, I've tried using the CSS on other parts of the code no luck. I'm using the Brackets editor

Comment: Works for me when I use your CSS and HTML in a snippet.

Comment: It's likely your CSS is overwritten somewhere; even if you have the `!important` tag. Are you sure you're not redefining  
`.button.new-quote:hover` anywhere?

Comment: @EH11353 Check my answer I found the problem why it was not working in the first place. There is nothing wrong with your selector.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine.

There are invisible characters hiding right before background-color.

So instead of being parsed as background-color,
it's probably being parsed as something like:
`%20%20%20background-color`
or something weird like that

```css
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0.3em 1.2em;
    margin:0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
    border:0.16em solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-radius:2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    text-align:center;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    background-color:#f14e4e;
}


.button.new-quote:hover{
  background-color:black;
  font-size:19px;
}
```

```html
   <input type="button" class="new-quote button" value='test'/>
```

Comment: Why `background` and not `background-color` ?

Comment: It will work with both,i`ll edit the answer soon with explantion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205464/what-is-the-difference-between-background-and-background-color
@s.kuznetsov

Comment: Yes, but agree, when the default is `background-color`, and in the hover is `background`, it looks a little ridiculous. Also, it can be confusing when you have huge code with a huge number of pseudo-classes.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 3):

> There is nothing wrong with your selector. You have correctly selected the button hover. I have run your code and guess what it is working fine.

I found the problem why did your code didn't work.

```
.button.new-quote:hover {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

This is your selector and now checks my selector

```
.button.new-quote:hover {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

Can you see a little difference here? That is extra whitespaces behind `background-color` property. I have removed all the spaces first and then added two spaces and then it worked as we all are expected.

In my opinion, I think you have copied the `background-color` property from somewhere else which has a copy policy to add hidden character spaces.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  border: 0.16em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: #f14e4e
}

.button.new-quote:hover {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="new-quote button" value='test' />
```

Comment: I am not sure about the reason but found the problem though.

Comment: Correct, good job on finding that out,
spent too much time to found that ...

Comment: I have applied prettier to that code then I came to know that there is something wrong with the format of the code.

Comment: Thank you! That does seem to be the problem, but why didn't the linter find it like it usually does in my Javascript? Does it not work on CSS code then?

Comment: ESLint is for javascript. There are few linters for CSS like scsslint or older CSSLint. Nowadays most CSS developers use `PostCSS`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```css
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0.3em 1.2em;
  margin:0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  border:0.16em solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-radius:2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  text-align:center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color:#f14e4e;
}


.button:hover{
  background-color:black !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="new-quote button" value= 'test'/>
```